Failed to load API definition - parser error in nest js when trying to fetch swagger docs
I am getting "Failed to load API definition" in nest js when trying to fetch swagger docs"
I'm getting this error when calling from Google Chrome. If called from Brave it's working fine.

This is my endpoint:
GET http://localhost:3100/ripa/docs-json net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 304 (Not Modified) 

Anyone can help me to fix with this, Anyone faced this error before?

Can you please share the swagger configurations?

Could it be the encoding of the file? It must be UTF8.
